# Slow SSMS connecting to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, connectivity, aws, windows-server

I have an AlwaysOn availability group in AWS EC2. 2 nodes, multisubnet, with 1 DC in one subnet, the other DC in a separate (3rd) subnet. All in the same VPC.

When anyone connects to either of the two AG nodes, either by IP address or by the listener IP address, the result is the same: the object explorer is extremely slow to load, SQL Agent node takes about 7 seconds to load, the connection itself takes a few seconds at least.

Odd thing is that pinging the ip addresses of either AG node is very responsive <44ms.

Using RDP to connect to a server on a different subnet or entirely separate VPC yields a very responsive, snappy SSMS experience.

This is bugging me because it forces people to RDP to do any SSMS work and unfortunately some folks use the primary AG node...

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese version 14.0.17099.0

Comment: I would try using the latest version. V17. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms . Every version they release seems to improve all around performance.

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese thats what I have. Version Information
The release number: 17.0
The build number for this release: 14.0.17099.0

Comment: I just realized that and was about to say it. My bad!

Comment: Do you have any other performance issues on the boxes, SQL wise?

Comment: @MarkWilkinson To a degree we do, I don't have nearly enough RAM for the database size, which means the workload is mostly IO bound. That said, the app is well written so performance issues are relatively minor at the moment and users have little/nothing to complain about.

Comment: When you use SSMS, and connect via object explorer, a lot of queries get executed to populate the explorer pane. What happens if you open a fresh SSMS window, cancel any initial connections it tries to make and just connect in the query window only?

Comment: @MarkWilkinson The same thing occurs, a very very slow login. I notice that the latency is considerably better (less slow) when using SQL authentication.